Installing poppler on macos without homebrew
Need to have poppler for python sourced from a network drive, so trying to find a way to install it without using homebrew and have it work for all ARM macs.
Can this be done?

Since brew install --compile-from-source will compile Poppler from source too (and yes, I know you said "without Homebrew", but that's beside the point), presumably yes, you could compile Poppler from source for distribution like this by hand too.
